# How do I change my apple ID on my iPad

Tags: ipad, apple-id

My apple ID on my iPad is not the same as my ID on the App Store. How do I change the ID on the iPad for the App Store?

Comment: There are two answers - one is the procedural - tap here and sign out of the old. The other is philosophical - how do I decide to abandon the apps purchased from the old ID and move to a new one. Which question is this? (Or perhaps both?)

Comment: Also - I'm going to close this as you can use an Apple ID in about 8 places on an iPad. Please edit the question to be more clear which place exactly you have your Apple ID (for email, for contacts, for home sharing, for iCloud, for the music store, etc...) Flag it for reopening once it's more clear what help you seek.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to go to the iTunes Store and App Store section in the Settings app and change the used Apple ID by tapping the Apple ID button.

[image: iTunes and App Store section in Settings App on iPad]

*Note that this capture is on a french iPad but button location are pretty much the same whatever the language used.*